# Are histogram bins left or right closed?

Tags: matplotlib

When plotting a histogram, do the bins include everything less than and equal to the bin value?

For instance, if I have a bin between 0 and 1, will that bin include everything greater than 0 but less than or equal to 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

> All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open. In other words, if bins is:
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> then the first bin is [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding 2) and the second [2, 3). The last bin, however, is [3, 4], which includes 4.

[`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) uses this NumPy method.